# Scripting Hashbang: How to get the python 2 interpreter?

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, python-2.7

I'm writing scripts that have to run on a number of different UNIX-like releases.
These are written in python 2.x.

Unfortunately, some newer releases have taken to calling this flavor binary "python2" instead of "python." Thus, "#!/usr/bin/env python" doesn't work to look for the proper installed python interpreter. Either I get the version 3 interpreter (bad) or no interpreter at all (worse!)

Is there a clever way to write a python script such that it will load with the python2 interpreter if installed, else the python interpreter if it's installed? I'd have to use other mechanisms to detect when "python" is a python3, but as I'm inside a python-like environment at that point, I can live with that.

I imagine I can write a ripple launcher, call it "findpython2," and use that as the #! interpreter for the script, but that means I have to install findpython2 in the search path, which is decidedly sub-optimal (these scripts are often called by absolute reference, so they're not in the path.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting inspiration from a famous perl hashbang trick, I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
"""":
python2 -c "" 2>/dev/null && exec python2 $0 ${1+"$@"}
python  -c "" 2>/dev/null && exec python  $0 ${1+"$@"}
echo "Could not find a python interpreter."
exit 1
"""

print "hello python"
```

Comment: If someone knows of a nicer way to test for the existence of a certain program in the path, I would love to know.

Comment: could also use: `$(type -p python2) && interp=python2 || interp=python; exec $interp "$0" ${1+"$@"}`

Comment: This actually answers the question. Sweet! Also, a fantastically terrible hack :-)

Comment: @JonWatte: if you only intend this to be useful on sane shells, you can use glenn's `type -p` suggestion. It works everywhere I tested, save on busybox' msh (and then, maybe there is an option for it on busybox menuconfig). OTOH, POSIX standardizes `type`, but not `type -p`.

Answer (score 4):

The unix way is to specify `python2` - most good distros will now install 2.x as `python2` and 3.x as `python3`, linking whichever is the *main* one to `python` (in most distros, 2.x). It is therefore best to specify the one you want explicitly.

This is all defined in [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) which states:

> This PEP provides a convention to ensure that Python scripts can
>   continue to be portable across *nix systems, regardless of the default
>   version of the Python interpreter (i.e. the version invoked by the
>   python command).
>
> - python2 will refer to some version of Python 2.x
> - python3 will refer to some version of Python 3.x
> - python should refer to the same target as python2 but may refer to python3 on some bleeding edge distributions

So if a distro isn't doing this, it is essentially a bug on their end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it ignores the effects of time. One important target distro is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (still three years of support left on that distro.) It does not install these links. It doesn't matter if you call it a "bug" or not, because it's the ground truth I need to live with. Also, while an attempt to solve my "actual" problem, this answer does not actually answer the question.

Comment: @JonWatte My suggestion is to provide a patching script that makes that link.

Comment: I do not want to require root, and I certainly do not want to require installing anything in /usr/bin.

Comment: @JonWatte Fair enough - I would recommend reporting the lack of that link as a bug though - as it's still supported and adding the link shouldn't do anything but help, I would imagine it has a good chance of being added in.

Comment: The problem is that Arch considers that link to point to python3, and I only have python2 installed. The link is there if I install python3. Which means that any scripts that use print and expect "python" to be "python3" are inherently incompatible. It will be ... interesting ... to see how that plays out when it hits mainstream distros like Ubuntu!

Comment: This is why the PEP recommends using python2 or python3 explicitly. In general, package maintainers can make the tiny patch where needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you must run on `python 2`, you best also call the interpreter as `python2`. I think most UNIX releases have symlinks from `/usr/bin/python/`and `/usr/bin/python2` to the appropriate binary.

Comment: See above -- this answer does not actually answer the question I asked.